# re-use pytest assertion logic for complex objects

Tags: python, pytest

How can I reuse the python "smart" reporting for objects?

E.g.:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, text, sequence):
        self.text = text
        self.sequence = sequence

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return type(self) == type(other) and self.text == other.text and self.sequence == other.sequence

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)
```

What I want is to get the assertion report, just as I would assert the primitive fields, e.g. (of course makes sense to not print attributes that satisfy the comparison operator - and concatenate together the failing attribute reports). Something like:

```
    def test_magic():
>       assert Foo(text='a', sequence=[1]) == Foo(text='a', sequence=[1, 2])
E       assert Foo(text='a', sequence=[1]) == Foo(text='a', sequence=[1, 2])
E           attribute `sequence`:
E              [1] == [1, 2]
E              Right contains more items, first extra item: 2
E        Use -v to get the full diff
```

Can I do this by writing some plugin, etc and calling in that the internal comparator? Or what is the recommended solution?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand.


If you try the code you wrote:
assert 'a' == 'a'
assert [0, 1] != [0]
assert [1, 2] == [1, 3]
                 
You will have a:
                  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
AssertionError

if you want you can define a function to check your assertion. Makes no difference if you try intrinsic constructs instead of classes. In python everything is an objects.

Comment: @Dr.Raghnar I don't get what you're implying, if I write it explicitly it works; however the point of the question is to not have to write it explicitly but make:
assert Foo(text='a', sequence=[1]) != Foo(text='a', sequence=[1, 2])
work like that; and yes I don't want to write a function for it that the user has then remember to call